# Superman vs. The Cyclotronic Man; what was the story arc?

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, superman

I once studied at a cyclotron laboratory (mid 1980's) and an already-old comic book circulated amongst the students with a cover showing "Superman vs. the Cyclotronic Man".

I think that the Cyclotronic man was vanquished at the end of the comic book via something that stops normal cyclotrons as well, but don't remember now what that is.

**Question:** Superman vs The Cyclotronic Man; what was the story arc? How did Superman prevail? Did The Cyclotronic Man die? Was this both the first and last time that The Cyclotronic Man appeared in Superman fiction, or where there other appearances?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is ***[Black Lightning Vol 1. #5](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Lightning_Vol_1_5)***, published in November 1977.

It was the final part of a three-part storyline, running through *Black Lightning Vol 1. #3-5*, but Superman only made a full appearance in this issue (he cameoed on the last page of the previous issue as well).

In this issue, both Black Lightning and Superman confront the supervillain known as the [Cyclotronic Man](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Ned_Creegan_(Earth-One)) (real name: Ned Creegan).

[image]

They ultimately defeat him by dunking him in a river, with Black Lightning noting that scientists use water to cool off a real cyclotron when one gets out of hand. This didn't kill Creegan, he was just knocked out.

[image]

According to [Creegan's list of appearances](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Ned_Creegan_(Earth-One)/Appearances) on the DC Fandom website, he appeared in five issues in total, as listed below in order of publication:

- *[Batman Vol. 1 #195](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_1_195)* (September 1967)
- *[Black Lightning Vol. 1 #3](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Lightning_Vol_1_3)* (July 1977)
- *[Black Lightning Vol. 1 #4](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Lightning_Vol_1_4)* (September 1977)
- *[Black Lightning Vol. 1 #5](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Lightning_Vol_1_5)* (November 1977)
- *[Batman and the Outsiders Vol. 1 #4](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman_and_the_Outsiders_Vol_1_4)* (November 1983)

Comment: Thanks! My strongest memory is "a cover showing 'Superman vs. the Cyclotronic Man'" Any idea which of these might be that? Did Creegan appear as "The Cyclotronic Man" in all five fo these?

Comment: None of Creegan's listed appearances have the phrase "Superman vs. the Cyclotronic Man" on the cover, but you might've seen a reprint with a different cover. Creegan appeared as the Cyclotronic Man in all the issues listed, except for _Black Lightning Vol. 1 #3_, where he remained in civilian attire. Of those five issues, _Black Lightning Vol. 1 #5_ is the only one where he and Superman fought. You can view the cover of that issue [here](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Lightning_Vol_1_5).

Comment: Ah, I'm slowly getting up to speed here. Yes, this is the cover I remember, from your first link https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/marvel_dc/images/7/7e/Black_Lightning_Vol_1_5.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/400?cb=20090116173647 My confusion lies in not being familiar with [Black Lightning](https://www.dccomics.com/characters/black-lightning) so I'm learning more than I'd expected! I think that I couldn't process the dynamic in the dialogue on the cover at the time, so just filed it under "Superman?" We were primarily focused on correlating the Cylotronic Man with the lab's director.